# Shorten function names in profling results with gprof2dot.py

Tags: python, profiling, gprof

I work usually with gprof + gprof2dot.py to profile C++ codes. A new code I am working with uses very long function names, so that the graphical results with gprof2dot.py are a mess. I wonder how can one shorten the function names so that they fit in a small box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can [narrow](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot#The_node_labels_are_too_wide._How_can_I_narrow_them?) the labels using gprof2py. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `--strip` (for shortening) and `--wrap` (for line wrapping) to `gprof2dot` and the labels get narrowed.

Seen [in the gprof2dot documentation here:](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot#the-node-labels-are-too-wide-how-can-i-narrow-them)

> ## The node labels are too wide. How can I narrow them?
>
> The node labels can get very wide when profiling C++ code, due to inclusion of scope, function arguments, and template arguments in demangled C++ function names.
>
> If you do not need function and template arguments information, then pass the `-s` / `--strip` option to strip them.
>
> If you want to keep all that information, or if the labels are still too wide, then you can pass the `-w` / `--wrap`, to wrap the labels. Note that because dot does not wrap labels automatically the label margins will not be perfectly aligned.

Comment: Hi @frans, As you noticed, the link in the first answer eventually [rotted away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot); that's why it's best to copy paste (with attribution!) the essential parts of the answer here in case the link rots away again.